# How do I jump to the next search result in a different window?

Tags: search, buffers

Sometimes I have two windows open and I search for a word that appears in both. Hitting <kbd>n</kbd> only cycles through the results in the active window.

It'd be really convenient to somehow jump to the next search result in all open windows.

Comment: Also recently discovered `:windo %s/pattern/replace/ge`, which searches & replaces in all windows 

Comment: While not an answer to the question, you could the files you want to search to the arglist, and then `vim /pattern/ ##` for all the results in quickfix

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:vimgrep` to do your search over the windows and use `'switchbuf'` with a value of at least `useopen`.

```
execute 'vimgrep //j ' . join(map(range(1, winnr('$')), '"#".winbufnr(v:val)'), ' ')
set switchbuf+=useopen
```

Now you can use the quickfix list to jump between matches you searched via `:cnext`/`:cprev` ([I suggest mapping these](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired)) or by using the quickfix window, `:copen`.

Personally, I can't really see myself using this kind of search. I typically need to search more files so I use `:vimgrep` or `:grep` (I use ripgrep as my `'grepprg'`). I use my own `:Cfilter` command to grep/filter the quickfix list.

```
function! s:cfilter(list, bang, pat)
  let [bool, operator] = a:bang ? ['&&', '!~'] : ['||', '=~']
  let pat = a:pat =~ '^/.*/$' ? a:pat[1:-2] : a:pat
  let pat = pat == '' ? @/ : pat
  call call('set'.a:list.'list', [(filter(call('get'.a:list.'list', []), "bufname(v:val.bufnr) ".operator." pat ".bool." v:val.text ".operator." pat"))])
  echo 'Filtered list: '.(a:bang ? 'not ' : '').'matching '.a:pat.' ('.len(call('get'.a:list.'list', [])).' items)'
endfunction
command! -nargs=1 -bang Cfilter call <SID>cfilter('qf', <bang>0, <q-args>)
command! -nargs=1 -bang Lfilter call <SID>cfilter('loc', <bang>0, <q-args>)
```

`:Cfilter foo` will filter the list for only entries with `foo` and `:Cfilter! foo` will filter the list with only entries without `foo`.

For more helps see:

```
:h :vimgrep
:h :_#n
:h join()
:h map()
:h range()
:h winnr()
:h winbufnr()
:h v:val
:h :execute
:h 'swb'
```